# show output from shell command run from Jscript

Tags: javascript, windows, internet-explorer, windows-shell

I want to run a shell command from jscript from IE on a Windows machine.

I have the following jscript function:

```
function execCommand( command ){
    var myShell =  new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
    myShell.Exec( "cmd /c " + command );
}
```

Under Windows, a new prompt window opens, the command is executed, and the window closes. Nevertheless, the prompt never shows any of the output from the command. While the command is running there is a blank prompt window.

How can I force the output of the program to show in the prompt window?

I have searched other questions, but I only found solutions for scripts running inside Windows Scripting Host, or for <strike>jscript</strike> javascript running in Mozilla.

I appreciate any hints.

Comment: As far as I know ,Jscript doesn't run in Mozilla. With usind Wscript.shell you have alerady used Windows Scripting Host.

Comment: If I understood your question, you want to keep the prompt window visible?

Comment: @reporter I thought I was using the Windows Scripting Host, but I don't have access to WScript.Echo(), nor can I instantiate an activeX object for WScript. The window is already showing, but the output of the application isn't visible. What I would like is to be able to see the output of the application in the prompt window. Thanks!

Comment: I used the parameter '/k' instead of '/c' but all my tries failed. Only exe files let keep the dosprompt visible. I'm sorry for my bad news.

Comment: @reporter thanks for your attempts. Yes, I also tried the /k parameter, the window remains visible until closed by the user, but no output from the application. The application I'm calling is actually a .exe console application. This application, if called from a prompt, gives its output to the prompt. I would expect to see its output even if it was invoked from jscript, but apparently not. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

[You can use the methods described here.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156605.aspx)

By exec you have to echo the stdout into a new message, by run you can use cmd or %comspec% with /K to prevent the window closing.

You should try the pause command too, maybe it helps...