# How to run a .JAR file with parameter from WinJS

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2012, jar, winjs

hello I want to know how to open a .JAR file with parameters from a metro app developed with WinJS in VS2012

in console the way to call them is

```
java -jar C:\folder\file1.txt
```

thanks in advance for your support

Comment: Maybe you could use `ActiveX`? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6275761/show-output-from-shell-command-run-from-jscript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't run a Java application under WinRT. You can't launch an external process either.

[Java is only supported on the Desktop](http://www.java.com/en/download/faq/win8_faq.xml) mode of Windows 8+.

To be approved, Windows Store applications must contain all functionality within the application package.

Comment: how do I add all functionallity withing the application package for making it work, or what is required for making it work :)

Comment: Java isn't supported. So, even if you could include the Jar file, you couldn't execute it.